# IONIC 3 - Clear application data programmatically

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an application that I need to clear cache and localstorage data after logout.

My logout method calls the `clearCache()` method. I'm using the cordova storage plugin.

```
  import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
  @Injectable()
  export class CacheService {   

    constructor(public cache: Storage) {}
    public clearCache(){
      this.cache.clear();
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }
```

The cache and localstorage is cleaning but when I go to > Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> My Application, it shows that the data and cache keeps stored on Android application data.
I can do it manually:

> Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> My Application -> Clear data

How can I clear application data programmatically as I do manually?

Comment: Hi @jraspante Do you really need to clear cache data? From that point you have application state like when you install it first time on device. Nothing else. I think it's more than enough to set user to LocalStorage, and after logout clear user data from it. Which plugin you use to clear cache data?

Comment: @MarkoSavic I'm getting data from an API and storing on cache to use that data offline. when I logged out and then logged in, the app is increasing memory usage. Im using Storage plugin.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with a growing app size (documents & data > 100MB). Even though the app isn't really storing anything locally.

I tracked down the problem (on iOS) to the app cache where InAppBrowser and HTTP.GET -calls are cached under Caches/[com.mybiz.app]/WebKit/NetworkCache/...

Now I've been testing deleting old caches at start up with the File-plugin:

```
this.file.removeRecursively(this.file.cacheDirectory, 'com.mybiz.app').catch(err => Pro.monitoring.exception(err))
```

Just don't know if this can effect Ionic Deploy updates. We may need to check for possible updates via the Deploy API before clearing cache.